# Can I overwrite get function of map in scala

Tags: scala, dictionary

I use map like this.

```
var mapList :Map[Array[String], Long] = new Map()
```

but, when I use `mapList.get( mapKey )`, It doesn't return matched value. even if the Array[String] has same elements and same sequence.

I think map saves reference and not data. So if reference(or pointer) is not same, it says it is not same. but I want to compare elements of Array not reference.

Is there a way I can do?

Comment: If you're not forced to use `Array` you could use a `Map[Vector[String], Long]`, which would work as you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Map` is relying on the comparison methods of the objects you use as a key. `Array` checks equality by reference. If instead of Array, you used one of Scala's immutable collection types, e.g. `List`, you would get your desired behaviour. Simple example:

```
val l = List(1,2,3)
val a = Array(1,2,3)

val lm = Map(l -> "Hello")
val am = Map(a -> "Hello")

lm.get(List(1,2,3)) //Some(Hello)

am.get(Array(1,2,3))//None
```